# Why D-brane can be attached to NS5 branes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, supersymmetry, branes

Is it possible (in analogy with D-brane) understand appearance of NS5 brane in perturbative string spectrum?

Why D-brane can be attached to NS5 branes?

I know that this can be described using notion of string dualities:

[image]

But I wanna to see more direct arguments for this.

Comment: It is related to M-theory. NS5-brane is M5-brane not wrapped around 11th dimension.

Comment: It's not likely to be simpler than the ST ladder for general Dp branes, but there is a more direct argument for NS5-D5 bound state, would you be interested?

Comment: @NiharKarve yes